# Bootstrap 5 basic layout, scrollable sidebar and fixed image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm kinda stuck creating a layout for a webapp I want to create.
This should be the layout
[LAYOUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHpIx.png)

On the "S" I want a sidebar menu that is scrollable and on the I it's going to be a big image that changes depending on what I choose on the sidebar.
The sidebar has to be scrollable independently from the rest of the page, and the page it self mustn't be scrollable. So the image should be fixed in the position (but responsive, so if I resize the screen, everything should shrink to be contained in the screen) and the sidebar scrollable.

At the moment I did the navbar but everything else I can't get it working.

EDIT:
That's the code I've done so far

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- GENERAL CONTAINER -->
<div class="container-fluid h-100 p-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- LOGO -->
      <a class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="../images/Logo-blue.png" alt="LOGO" style="width: calc(7vh + 7vw)" />
      </a>
      <!-- USER ICON + USER NAME + USER OPTION CONTAINER -->
      <div class="dropdown pe-5">
        <a class="btn text-white dropdown-toggle btntoggle text-uppercase" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <!-- USER ICON -->
          <i class="bi bi-person-circle pe-1"></i>
          <!-- USER NAME -->
          Judith Scoltock
        </a>
        <!-- USER OPTION -->
        <ul class="dropdown-menu menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item user-item text-white" href="#">Personalizza profilo</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item user-item text-white" href="#">I miei allenamenti</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item user-item text-white" href="#">Classifica</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item user-item text-white" href="#">Accedi al corso</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item user-item text-white" href="#">Contattaci</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item user-item text-white" href="#">Esci</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <!-- MENU CONTAINER -->
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 scroll">
        MENU<br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> MENU
        <br/> ULTIMO
        <br/>
      </div>
      <!-- IMGS CONTAINER -->
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 border border-danger">
        IMMAGINE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show your attempt and the issue/errors you are facing? We can't write this for you, but provided you have made a good faith attempt, we can certainly help :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @CanO'Spam I've edited my question with some code!

Answer (score 0):

Use a navbar for logo-username and for the menu and I use regular container > row > col. But clear paddings and gaps with this way you can create that UI. ON the mobile version just hide Menu and use offcanvas component of bootstrap5.

Example
.navbar
.container-fluid.p-0
.row.g-0
.col-md-3 "Menu"
.col-md-9 "Image"

Comment: I've edited my question with some code!